# Why I cannot access my website from the internet only from localhost

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have installed teampulse http://www.telerik.com/team-productivity-tools.aspx community. I add in bindings my domain name with port 9898 like it is with localhost. I can connect through localhost but not throuh the domain. Why ?

Comment: "cannot connect" is a bit vague; which error (if any) do you experience? which error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked windows firewall? You probably need to open tcp port 9898. I'm pretty sure that would be blocked by default.

Comment: ok but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452260/how-to-open-port-on-iis-firewall